# What webrtc media constraints should I use to remove all processing / effects on the audio?

Tags: webrtc, web-audio-api

I am currently using

```js
  var mediaOptions = { 
        audio: {
          optional: {
            sourceId: this.get('audioInputId'),
            googAutoGainControl: false,
            googNoiseSuppression: false,
            googEchoCancellation: false,
            googHighpassFilter: false
          }
        }
    }
```

Is there anything else I should be turning off?  I'm recording the audio so it needs to be untouched by any processing.

I'm noticing that sometimes there is  a ducking effect on one end when others are talking.

Also, are there any flags for Firefox?  Does Firefox respect any of these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Firefox you should be fine only with

```
    audio : {
        "mandatory": {
            "echoCancellation": "false"
        }
    }
```

and in Chrome

```
        audio : {
            "mandatory": {
                "googEchoCancellation": "false",
                "googNoiseSuppression": "false",
                "googHighpassFilter": "false",
                "googTypingNoiseDetection": "false"
            },
            "optional": []
        }
```

But disabling these features it's usually done if you want to stream music. If you stream voice I think it's recommended to leave them on.

The ducking effect on voice streaming is not because of any processing, rather of a slow network (low bandwidth or high latency).

Comment: Hey Adrian, Thanks for the response.  I'll try out those settings.  I'm curious what you mean about the ducking effect being cause by a slow network.  Why would this be the case?  For some context, I'm recording each participant's local audio stream, not the audio that comes over the wire.  Would latency affect the quality of the local stream somehow?

Comment: Did you notice that ducking effect on the recorded local audio stream? It shouldn't be affected by the network quality. On the other hand CPU load can affect this.

Comment: Yes, I am getting reports of the local audio being affected.  That the audio gets distorted or muddy when people talk over each other.

Comment: Have you tried with the settings above? Do you notice the same issues?

Comment: In the process of see if this makes a difference.  I'll report back in a week or so.

Comment: Just a follow up on this.  Turning off echo cancellation does in fact fix the muddy sound when people talk over each other.  However, if the participants audio is leaking from their headphones, instead of muddy audio, you get the leaking audio recorded.  The solution is really to just make sure that there aren't any echos to cancel in the first place.